# Using Python to log-in to a website that has Ajax Pop-up login page using Requests.Session

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler, python-requests

I am trying to gather some data from www.mutualart.com, however, the website has a Ajax log-in form which pops up by clicking 'log-in'. Therefore, when I was trying to use Requests Session's post method to log in to this website, it does not work.

To obtain premium data from the website, I need to log in to the website and maintain the cookie to access the information I need.

How can I login to website using post method in this situation?

```
    import requests
    from lxml import htmlfrom bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import sys

    EMAIL = ''
    PASSWORD = ''

    MainUrl = 'https://www.mutualart.com'


    payload = {
        'email': EMAIL,
        'txtUserPassword': PASSWORD
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:

        login_req = s.post(MainUrl, data=login_data)

        url = 'https://www.mutualart.com/Artwork/Vue-de-Franche-Comte/9CDD9A00EE80E8C9'

        post_one = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(post_one.text, 'lxml')

        estimate = soup.find_all('div',class_='v2__artwork-detail__price-col')
        name = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'v2__artwork-detail__section')

        print estimate #This should be the data that can be accessed by premium subscription
        print login_req.status_code #The connection seems to be there
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to gain access with my credentials using the below url in
place of 'MainUrl'.

'https://www.mutualart.com/Ajax/LogIn/UserControlLogin'

Chrome's "Dev Tools" comes in handy when viewing network activity in relation to websites (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Within the network tab ensure you're recording & have the preserve log toggled.

Side note: Do to my current reputation I am unable to reply with a comment, which I feel would be better suited for my response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill try with this!